# Reload page and take the user where the cursor is

Tags: php, jquery, html

Is it possible to take the user where the cursor is after reloading the page? I'm enabling a `<textarea>` on the basis of some URL parameters on page reload using PHP. But in the new window the textarea will open on the bottom of the page. If the page is already lengthy the textarea will be hidden beneath.

Is there any way so that after reloading the page the textarea appears on the viewport so that it can be filled?

I tried:

```
<a href="url/to/page?write#ok">Write</a>
...
<a href="#ok">#<a> <!-- setting a bookmark to get the viewport here -->
<textarea><textarea>
```

I know there are plenty of solutions using AJAX, using lightbox etc. But I need a generic way, may be HTML or a server-side solution. Or, in a nay-say it can be jQuery.

Comment: Do you want the user to focus in as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear that you are using the anchor (or bookmark, as you called it) correctly. If you give the `<textarea>` tag an id of "ok" you should be able to link directly to that area of the page by using the # in your link to the page. Example: `somepage.html#ok`

There is no need to use the `<a>` tag to create an anchor. That is outdated.